# How to design enterprise level application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, web-applications, architecture

I am a freelance software engineer, I have worked in few areas of computer science, I have made some e-commerce websites in the past. Now I have an opportunity to build a big enterprise level system. I can not disclose specifics about the application due to NDA I signed so pardon me if my question seems broad, let me know in the comments if you require clarification. I appreciate your help.

**About Application:**

> In this application, I would require building a system like uber, there will be people at my client's end for
>   resolving customer issues, so a CRM is also needed. 
>   customers will be using this app, so I have
>   to design a separate system that can manage tickets and access
>   database.

My question is where to start designing such application. I guess I would require DynamoDB and AWS, I have divided modules into parts such as Client App, Database, Dashboard etc. I want to know if there is some case study that can help me decide how to design such large application. 

I found [this link](http://chateau-logic.com/content/quick-guide-designing-enterprise-level-application) useful, it gave me an idea of work, but still, I believe it's a long way from money shot.

[EDIT]
To narrow down the scope of the question, What Backend server should be chosen for an application that will serve one hundred thousand users per hour. I will use Mongo DB as the database, and Python as backend scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM has a nice article on Enterprise Architecture,

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/enterprise-architecture-maximum-value/

Before building the software, design how it should work and choose your software components according to that.

Previously you might need costly infrastructure to think something, with recent technologies, you can do them at a lower cost. You need to apply the right architecture and engineering when designing your application.

Comment: Thanks man , I will look into it

Comment: Thank you sir , the post helped , now I have some sane direction .

Comment: You are welcome. Glad this could be of help to start with.